# Table output with different variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I modify my script to print output in a table, like in this screenshot?

[image: Desired output]

```
ruta=$1
nom=$2
size=$3
mod=$4
search="$(find "$ruta" -iname "*$nom*" -size $size -mtime $mod)"
fichero="$(ls -lh $search | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"; OFS="\t"}{print$NF}')"
mida="$(ls -lh $search | awk '{print$5}')"
modificado="$(ls -l --full-time $search | awk '{print$6}')"
path="$(ls -d $search | awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"; OFS="/"} {$NF=""; print$0,$NF}')"
#echo $search
echo -e "\e[31mNOMBRE DEL FICHERO\n\e[0m$fichero" 
echo
echo -e "\e[31mTAMAÑO\n\e[0m$mida" 
echo
echo -e "$modificado"
echo
echo -e "$path"
echo
```

Comment: What do you mean by "output by tab"? You can print a tab character in bash by `echo -e '\t'`.

Comment: like picture shows...i want thosse 3 files (or what it find) tabulated not listed under other. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive packets of information from the different input sub-commands like `search`, `fichero` etc. That means better names are `searches`, `ficheros` etc.

If you assign those to bash arrays you may loop afterwards like:

```sh
# read shell command into array ()
result=($(find /var/log -type f))

# show found number of elements
echo "Elements found: ${#result[@]}"

# loop elements by counter
for ((i=0; i<${#result[@]}; i++))
do
  echo ${result[$i]}
done

echo "-----"

# print all content
echo ${result[@]}
```

Interesting article for using bash arrays: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/

```sh
ruta=$1
nom=$2
size=$3
mod=$4

search=($(find "$ruta" -not -type d -iname "*$nom*" -size $size -mtime $mod))

echo -e "FICHERO\tTAMANO\tMODIFICATION\tRUTA"

for ((i=0; i<${#search[@]}; i++))
do
  fichero=$(basename ${search[$i]})
  mida=$(stat -f "%z" ${search[$i]})
  modificado=$(stat -t "%Y-%m-%d" -f "%Sm" ${search[$i]})
  path=$(dirname ${search[$i]})

  echo -e "$fichero\c"
  echo -e "\t$mida\c"
  echo -e "\t$modificado\c"
  echo -e "\t$path\c"
  echo
done
```

And another simplified variant with printf output and another for loop without array:

```sh
ruta=$1
nom=$2
size=$3
mod=$4

search=$(find "$ruta" -not -type d -iname "*$nom*" -size $size -mtime $mod 2>/dev/null)

printf "%s %38s  %12s  %s\n" "FICHERO" "TAMANO" "MODIFICATION" "RUTA"
printf "%s\n" "--------------------------------------------------------------------"

for file in ${search}
do
  fichero=$(basename $file)
  mida=$(stat -f "%z" $file)
  modificado=$(stat -t "%Y-%m-%d" -f "%Sm" $file)
  path=$(dirname $file)

  printf "%35s %10s  %12s  %s\n" $fichero $mida $modificado $path
done
```

Comment: I REALLY APPRECIATE YOUR HELP Tom. it does only find 1 file and it works. but what i need is an script to find files from / and your answer does only if echo ${search[@]}..i think i got the problem in the way to go for it..i need that output describes by tab NameOfFile(just file without path) - SIZE-DATE(last modify) - PATH(without name)

Comment: my picture on top.. shows those 3 files one bye one tabulated at front of its self size, date mod, path..

Comment: Hi @AndrésDaza check my updated answer - should now fullfill your wishlist. All other information you may add yourself. Cheers, Tom

Comment: @AndrésDaza checkout the last variant of my answer - should completely solve your question.

Comment: absolutely it does...Tom..it works..and best part..understood.